# Broken Submission Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a survey form that we use for our clients. It is a series of multiple choices questions, and a few text field entries. At the end, you click "submit" and an email is sent containing all the responses to our Quality Manager. Recently, the form stopped working, and I found many people who successfully fixed the issue by changing docslist to DriveApp.  However, now I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "response" from undefined. (line 10, file "")
```

The entire code reads as follows:

```
/// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1vCv-NR9c2G5q6f6EJ2CL4zAEQe_37OE7MgsSLTIKheY"; // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName = "ClientSurvey";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));

var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  Logger.log(formResponses[0].toString());

  var service_type = formResponses[0].getResponse().toString();

var email_address = "notrealaddress@ntainc.com, notrealaddress@ntainc.com"
//var service_type = e.values[0];
 var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();  

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+timeStamp)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();



// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keyServiceType', service_type);


 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    copyBody.appendParagraph(formResponses[i].getItem().getTitle().toString());
    copyBody.appendParagraph(formResponses[i].getResponse().toString());
    copyBody.appendParagraph(" ");

  }


// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Customer Survey";
var body = "Here is a New Customer Survey";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: I used your code (the part that gets the response from e and the part that sends the email) and it worked for me. Do you have configured the triggers of the Form? in the script editor on the left of the "Run" button there is a clock, click on it and check if the trigger is configured.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I dont have enough rep to comment yet.
Check your trigger, there is two types of FormSubmit triggers, one for sheets and one for forms, if you are using the wrong one that could be what is causing your issues.

Comment: Are you getting that error when testing the code directly in the Apss script environment? if that's the case then the error is expected because you are no setting the variable "e". Only when the function is executed as a trigger (when users submit a form) then his variable is populated.

Comment: I was testing in Apps, but, I also did a test entry on the form, and it generates an error email that comes back.